# Internationalization, Localization and Native American languages in Windows

Tags: windows, user-interface, localization, internationalization, multilingual

My co-workers posed an interesting question to me a few weeks ago, and I was wondering if you all could help, or at least point me in sort of the right direction.

I work for a tribal casino, and one of the people who does more direct work with Native American languages was in the other day.. We were talking about the longevity and problems with maintenance of Native American languages. Right now people learn the languages as young children in special classes, but lose them as they grow older as there was no way to reinforce the language as they live their daily life. After a while of talking about this, he asked me if there was a way to change the text in windows to match their language, so they can create more advanced classes for children to study as they grow older. Is there a way to customize the windows UI for a language not already provided in the set? Right now, I understand there is a font for the Cherokee language, but I haven’t been able to find out how to make a remapping of the UI text for other Native languages. Do you have any ideas about how to do this, or know someone else who might know?

Comment: Localizing Windows is a major undertaking and can only be done by Microsoft.  A language pack is around half a gigabyte, compressed.  Contact them directly, they may be sympathetic to your cause.

Comment: "Sympathy doesn't have any place in business"!!! (at-least for Microsoft :))

Comment: Well, I'd like to know who I need to talk to to even get started? I acknowledge that it's not a simple process.

Comment: It's off topic, but I believe that there are some Linux versions supporting some of these languages. I don't think there ever be Windows version available (unless MS adopts some crowdsourcing platform for L10n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vista added capabilities to do "light" translations of a good chunk of the interface using something called [Language Interface Packs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688177).  Perhaps there's a LIP for one of the languages you're interested in.

Comment: Not quite at that site, but I found [this](http://www.microsoft.com/about/corporatecitizenship/en-us/community-tools/llp/) on an associated link. I hope it works, thank you for the help!

Comment: Well, we are contacting a Microsoft rep, to see how best to stat the process. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!